# Problemas en #include C++

Tags: c++

pues cuando quiero compilar el programa me da error en ambos #include iostream e #include sstream, (lo pongo aqui pues en el codigo que pegué no lo muestra) 
me da el error de 'In file from'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;


typedef struct{

int num;
int cont;
int suma;
stringstream ss;

}punto;

punto funcion1();
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   //Se crea variable de tipo 'punto'
    punto datos;

   //Se define el valor de la variable coordenadaA mediate el retorno de la funcion PedirPunto()
    datos = funcion1();

    //se trabaja con los valores de la estructura.
    cout<<"suma: "<<datos.suma<<endl;
    cout<<"numeros: "<<datos.num<<endl;
    cout<<"veces: "<<datos.cont<<endl;

    return 0;
}

punto funcion1()
{

    punto valor;
    cout<<"Ingrese el número: ";cin>>valor.num;
    valor.cont = 0;
    valor.suma = 0;
    while (valor.num > 0)
    {
        valor.suma = valor.suma + valor.num;
        valor.cont++;
        valor.ss<<valor.num<<",";
        cout<<"Ingrese otro número: ";cin>>valor.num;          
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: `In file from` no dice nada con respecto al error que se está presentando en el programa, si crees que *C++* no es un lenguaje de programación no es muy instructivo puedes **cambiarte**. Mi lenguaje de programación favorito es *PHP*.

Comment: la linea mala es esta `funcion PedirPunto()` estas inicializando una variable tipo funcion pero al nombre le pones una funcion??? eso esta muy mal el objeto function nisiquiera existe

Comment: Perdon, esa linea es del comentario, cuando se sube el codigo lo toma asi, sin ser parte del comentario

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si te das cuenta, el verdadero error lo tienes aquí: `datos = funcion1();`. Estás asignando a una instancia otra instancia, por lo que se hace uso del operador asignación. No he usado nunca `stringstream` pero tiene toda la pinta de no tener implementado dicho operador o lo tiene para uso privado. Te respondo con una forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes realmente en esta línea de tu código:

```
datos = funcion1();
```

Estás asignando a una estructura declarada de manera estática el valor devuelto por una función. Por norma general se copian cada uno de los valores y si alguno es una clase se llama al operador asignación (`=`), pero el error que te está dando es que éste es privado:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:795:5: error:
>   ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
>      operator=(const ios_base&);
>      ^
> ```

Y aquí te dice que la primera vez que necesita ese operador es en la asignación que te indiqué:

> ```
> pr.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> pr.cpp:27:11: note:
>   synthesized method ‘punto& punto::operator=(const punto&)’ first required here 
>      datos = funcion1();
>            ^
> ```

De modo que para evitar el disparo del operador asignación deberías pasar como parámetro el dato que quieres modificar en vez de devolverlo como valor:

```
void funcion1(punto *);
```

La llamada cambiaría a un paso de parámetro por referencia:

```
funcion1(&datos);
```

De esta manera la función cambia en su definición y el acceso a los datos se haría con `->` y no con `.`:

```
void funcion1(punto *valor)
{

    cout<<"Ingrese el número: ";cin>>valor->num;
    valor->cont = 0;
    valor->suma = 0;
    while (valor->num > 0)
    {
        valor->suma = valor->suma + valor->num;
        valor->cont++;
        valor->ss << valor->num << ",";
        cout << "Ingrese otro número: ";
        cin >> valor->num;
    }
}
```

El código completo final sería:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  int num;
  int cont;
  int suma;
  std::stringstream ss;
} punto;

void funcion1(punto *);
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   //Se crea variable de tipo 'punto'
    punto datos;

   //Se define el valor de la variable coordenadaA mediate el retorno de la funcion PedirPunto()
    funcion1(&datos);

    //se trabaja con los valores de la estructura.
    cout << "suma: " << datos.suma << endl;
    cout << "numeros: " << datos.num << endl;
    cout << "veces: " << datos.cont << endl;

    return 0;
}

void funcion1(punto *valor)
{

    cout << "Ingrese el número: ";
    cin >> valor->num;
    valor->cont = 0;
    valor->suma = 0;
    while (valor->num > 0)
    {
        valor->suma = valor->suma + valor->num;
        valor->cont++;
        valor->ss << valor->num << ",";
        cout << "Ingrese otro número: ";
        cin >> valor->num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para comentar este error existe [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104712/c%c3%b3mo-devover-un-stringstream-de-una-funcion).

Comment: Considera mover la respuesta de sitio :)

Comment: Gracias, no conocía la existencia de la otra (y tampoco el motivo por el que no cerró ésta o dejar un comentario para llevarnos a la otra). Como no sé como moverla copiaré/pegaré el contenido.

Comment: Sí, cuando te dije de mover la respueta me refería a copiarla y después a borrar esta... no hay ningún comando que permita mover la respuesta de una pregunta a otra