# ¿Cómo devolver un stringstream de una función?

Tags: c++

Pues cuando le doy en compilar el programa me da error, investigando encontré que era porque no puedo devolver un stringstream como una copia, pero hay otras formas de devolverlo, ¿pueden ayudarme?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


typedef struct{

    int num;
    int cont;
    int suma;
    stringstream ss;

}punto;

punto funcion1();
/*
 * 
 */
int main(void) {

    punto datos;
    datos = funcion1();

    cout<<"suma: "<<datos.suma<<endl;
    cout<<"numeros: "<<datos.num<<endl;
    cout<<"veces: "<<datos.cont<<endl;

    return 0;
}

punto funcion1()
{

    punto valor;
    stringstream valor.ss;
    cout<<"Ingrese el número: ";cin>>valor.num;
    valor.cont = 0;
    valor.suma = 0;
    while (valor.num > 0)
    {
        valor.suma = valor.suma + valor.num;
        valor.cont++;
        valor.ss<<valor.num<<",";
        cout<<"Ingrese otro número: ";cin>>valor.num;          
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: debes aclarar cual es el error que te devuelve..

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como [te respondí en la otra pregunta que hiciste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104673/problemas-en-include-c/104766#104766), el problema lo tienes realmente en esta línea de tu código por el tema que comentas, no se puede hacer una copia de un `stringstream`:

```
datos = funcion1();
```

Por norma general se copian cada uno de los valores y si alguno es una clase se llama al operador asignación (`=`), pero el error que te está dando es que éste es privado:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:795:5: error:
>   ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
>      operator=(const ios_base&);
>      ^
> ```

Y aquí te dice que la primera vez que necesita ese operador es en la asignación que te indiqué:

> ```
> pr.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> pr.cpp:27:11: note:
>   synthesized method ‘punto& punto::operator=(const punto&)’ first required here 
>      datos = funcion1();
>            ^
> ```

Ese es el problema real que has tenido, la imposibilidad de usar el operador asignación.

Una forma de evitar el disparo de dicho operador deberías pasar como parámetro el dato que quieres modificar en vez de devolverlo como valor:

```
void funcion1(punto *);
```

La llamada cambiaría a un paso de parámetro por referencia:

```
funcion1(&datos);
```

De esta manera la función cambia en su definición y el acceso a los datos se haría con `->` y no con `.`:

```
void funcion1(punto *valor)
{

    cout<<"Ingrese el número: ";cin>>valor->num;
    valor->cont = 0;
    valor->suma = 0;
    while (valor->num > 0)
    {
        valor->suma = valor->suma + valor->num;
        valor->cont++;
        valor->ss << valor->num << ",";
        cout << "Ingrese otro número: ";
        cin >> valor->num;
    }
}
```

El código completo final sería:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  int num;
  int cont;
  int suma;
  std::stringstream ss;
} punto;

void funcion1(punto *);
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   //Se crea variable de tipo 'punto'
    punto datos;

   //Se define el valor de la variable coordenadaA mediate el retorno de la funcion PedirPunto()
    funcion1(&datos);

    //se trabaja con los valores de la estructura.
    cout << "suma: " << datos.suma << endl;
    cout << "numeros: " << datos.num << endl;
    cout << "veces: " << datos.cont << endl;

    /* Dos formas de obtener un string de un stringstream */
    string enumeracion;
    datos.ss >> enumeracion;
    cout << "Números introducidos: " << datos.ss.str() <<
      " o " << enumeracion << endl;

    return 0;
}

void funcion1(punto *valor)
{

    cout << "Ingrese el número: ";
    cin >> valor->num;
    valor->cont = 0;
    valor->suma = 0;
    while (valor->num > 0)
    {
        valor->suma = valor->suma + valor->num;
        valor->cont++;
        valor->ss << valor->num << ",";
        cout << "Ingrese otro número: ";
        cin >> valor->num;
    }
}
```

Ahora sí, es mejor evitar el uso que le das a `stringstream` como te recomienda [@eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) y si lo que deseas es almacenar un listado de números es mejor usar una lista ([`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)) para ello.

Comment: Umm, pero al imprimir los datos no da la cadena, osea no imprime los números ingresados, y con lo de vectores, tienes una página de confianza para aprender a usarlos?

Comment: Porque en tu código no lo haces y no preguntas cómo hacerlo en tu pregunta. He modificado mi respuesta para incluir dos formas de obtener las información en forma de cadena. Como página de referencia yo siempre uso ésta: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). Ahí encontrarás todo lo necesario de C++ en profundidad y detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero antes de nada aclarar que C++ **no es C**.

```
// Esto es C (aunque stringstream no exista en C)
typedef struct{

    int num;
    int cont;
    int suma;
    stringstream ss;

}punto;

// Esto es C++ -> no hace falta typedef
struct punto
{
    int num;
    int cont;
    int suma;
    stringstream ss;
};
```

Además, el código no te va a compilar aunque no intentes devolver un `stringstream`:

```
punto funcion1()
{

    punto valor;
    stringstream valor.ss; // <---
```

Esa última línea no va a compilar jamás. La clase `punto` **ya tiene** un miembro `ss`. No necesitas redeclararlo.

Aclarados estos puntos podemos seguir.

La clase `stringstream` es una utilidad que permite construir cadenas de caracteres de forma sencilla. En ningún momento se pretende su uso como miembro de una clase o estructura.

Según se refleja en tu código, estás utilizando este *stream* para almacenar la lista de números así que podríamos decir que tienes dos opciones:

1. Almacenas los números en un vector. Cuando necesites imprimir la secuencia tendrás que iterar el mismo para imprimir el resultado:

   ```
   struct punto
   {
       int num;
       int cont;
       int suma;
       std::vector<int> numeros;
   };

   while (valor.num > 0)
   {
       valor.suma = valor.suma + valor.num;
       valor.cont++;
       valor.numeros.push_back(valor.num);

       cout<<"Ingrese otro número: ";
       cin>>valor.num;          
   }

   // En tu código no imprimes nunca el resultado de ss. El equivalente podría ser
   for( size_t i=0; i<valor.numeros.size(); i++ )
   {
     if( i > 0 ) std::cout << ',';
     std::cout << valor.numeros[i];
   }
   ```
2. Amacenas la lista de números en una cadena.

   ```
   struct punto
   {
       int num;
       int cont;
       int suma;
       std::string numeros;
   };

   stringstream ss;
   while (valor.num > 0)
   {
       valor.suma = valor.suma + valor.num;
       valor.cont++;
       ss << valor.num << ",";

       cout<<"Ingrese otro número: ";
       cin>>valor.num;          
   }

   valor.numeros = ss.str();

   // En tu código no imprimes nunca el resultado de ss. El equivalente podría ser
   std::cout << valor.numeros;
   ```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice de esa manera, pues solo esa habia encontrado, no he tocado el tema de vectores

Comment: @CheleJavier he editado la respuesta que tenía una pequeña errata en la segunda opción (la de almacenar el resultado en una cadena de texto)